# command line for getting information about status of disk?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, diskpart

Here is the scenario, 
I have Windows Server 2003 and 2008 which is connected LUNs. I wanted to get status of the disk if disks are online or offline using command line.

I'm trying to execute `diskpart /s sample.txt` and 
`sample.txt` contains

```
SELECT DISK=1
CREATE PARTITION primary
```

So, the above command is not getting executed , because the disk is offline.
Is there any native "command line utility" or script to check the status of LUNs assigned to system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Launch `DISKPART` and run `LIST DISK`. The status column will show if they're online or not.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code to get the status of a drive.  This is powershell code.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_diskdrive -Property STATUS
```

Answer (score 1):

Use WMIC: `WMIC DISKDRIVE GET Availability,Index,Caption`

The values for availability can be found [in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Get-WmiObject -Class win32_diskdrive | fl deviceid,serialnumber

Comment: This answer needs explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! It looks like you may have the knowledge to provide good Answer here, but please consider reading [How do I write a good Answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) in our help center and then revise the Answer. Your Commands/Code/Settings may technically be the solution but  some explanation is welcome. Also please use [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts to improve their readability, convention is to mark command/scripts/code as `code`. Thanks in advance.